# Is this postulate about the past perfect and past perfect continuous valid?

Tags: meaning, grammar

1. If the second action of the two entails the ending of the first, then the past perfect simple emphasises completion, while the past perfect continuous emphasises duration.

> I had waited for three hours when you finally arrived.
> *Emphasises the completion of the action "Waiting"*.

> I had been waiting for three hours when you finally arrived.
> *Emphasises the duration of the action "Waiting"*.

And in both sentences the meaning is the same: I waited for three hours, then you arrived.

2. If the second action however, doesn't entail the ending of the first, then the past perfect simple means the ending and completion of the first action, while the past perfect continuous means that the first action could've **either** went on, or stopped at that moment.

> I had worked for three hours when the manager came.
> *He came and I had already finished working those 3 hours*.

> I had been working for three hours when the manager came.
> *Three hours exactly had passed the moment he came. Maybe he came to check how the work was going, and didn't interrupt and left, so I resumed working. And maybe he asked me to come to him, so that I stopped working. I don't know which of these two speculations or if something else happened, so both meanings are possible*.

Comment: In the *had waited* example, I would prefer *before you arrived*

Comment: What @Henry said. In general, *I **had done** X **before** Y happened* and *I **was doing** X **when** Y happened* are far more natural than *I **had done** X **when** Y happened* or *I **was doing** X **before** Y happened*.

Comment: Thanks for the note, both. I intended that "when" meant: "When suddenly" you arrived, or "when at a certain moment" you arrived, not in the sense of that "when" denotes that vague time period that means "around that time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thoughts are almost accurate.

> 1. If the second action of the two entails the ending of the first, then the past perfect simple emphasises completion, while the past perfect continuous emphasises duration.
>
> I had waited for three hours when you finally arrived.
> *<s>Emphasises the completion of the action "Waiting"</s>*.

It indicates that the action was complete at the time referred to. This does not mean that the job itself was completed - it merely indicates a hiatus in the job when the manager arrived.

> I had been waiting for three hours when you finally arrived.

> <s>Emphasises the duration of the action "Waiting"</s>.

It indicates that the action has started but was incomplete at the time referred to.

> <s>And in both sentences the meaning is the same: I waited for three hours, then you arrived.</s>

You made a distinction, therefore the claim that they are the same cannot be true.

The other problem is that the verb you have chosen (to wait) is durative: this will obscure the point of your example.

> 2. If the second action however, doesn't entail the ending of the first, then the past perfect simple means the ending and completion of the first action, while the past perfect continuous means that the first action could've **either** <s>went on</s> continued, or stopped at that moment.

> I had worked for three hours when the manager came.
> *He came and I had already finished working those 3 hours*.

This contradicts your earlier claim.

> I had been working for three hours when the manager came.
> Three hours <s>exactly</s> *[There is no “**exactly**” in the original example.]* had passed the moment he came. Maybe he came to check how the work was going, and didn't interrupt and left, so I resumed working. And maybe he asked me to come to him, so that I stopped working. I don't know which of these two speculations or if something else happened, so both meanings are possible.

You have missed the point of the past perfect. Its use is to provide context and background to the “main event”, i.e. the “theme” of the sentence.

In “I had been working for three hours when the manager came”, what you are telling us is that the manager arrived - the theme is  *the manager came*.  “I had been working for three hours” is background/context to the manager’s arrival.

“I had been working for three hours” tells us that the process of working had started but was incomplete – you were still working when the manager arrived. The cause of this meaning is *not* the duration but the incompleteness - regardless of what you did when the manager arrived - the intention was to continue as the job was incomplete.

Finally, what happens after the manager leaves is not the concern of the verb form that you have used so it indicates nothing.

Comment: I actually meant that the two examples of me and the manager were two separate situations. Isn't the contradiction void then? The "contradiction"  not the difference in meaning.

Comment: Oh! In the " I had waited" example, the "Waiting" was complete, as it is in the past perfect simple, and in the "I had been waiting" example, the action of waiting was incomplete NOT the action of waiting 3 hours. I was still waiting and didn't finish waiting, but 3 hours had already passed.

Comment: What if I make the first 2 examples: A. "I had waited 'for you' for 3 hours when you finally arrived", and B. "I had been waiting 'for you' for 3 hours when you finally arrived". Won't then the completion occur in both cases? *I am describing the same one situation here.

Comment: And I am truely thankful for your answer. It has clarified several concepts for me.

Comment: But if I shouldn't have used "wait", what should I have used then? I thought that "duration" was necessary, or else I wouldn't have been able to use a continuous tense.

Comment: Isn't there one small exception?  Imagine you arrive three hours late and salute with: "Hi, Joe, nice to see you.".  You might say:  "Nice to see you? I've waited for you for three hours in the rain and all you can say is 'nice to see you?!'.  It might be argued that   you would say, in that case, "I have been waiting" rather than just 'have waited'.  But I think the latter is not incorrect grammatical usage.  But my exception is temporally marginal. You are in the final seconds, you might say, of the sensation of waiting.

Comment: @Tuffy *Isn't there one small exception?* If you say "I have waited", you acknowledge that the waiting has ceased upon arrival. If you say "have been waiting" you are indicating a past action that, at the time referred to, had not finished. -- As I mentioned, "to wait" is strongly durative and thus can be confusing. Compare "I had hit him" and "I had been hitting him."

Answer (score 0):

@Greybeard I think I may be stretching things, but (in the descriptivist world I inhabit), nobody tries to correct my grammar or accidence if I speak like that, not even the online grammar checker.  I agree about the durative aspect.  But what if I replaced 'waited' with 'stood' or even the phrase 'been standing?  As I speak, I am still standing, so that it has not ended.  I suppose my thought is that there is a grey area in cases where past blends into present.